# Proxymillion IPs with cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am using proxymillion to scrape data from google. I am using cURL but not getting the result and getting error Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1

my code

```
$proxies[] = 'username:password@IP:port';  // Some proxies require user, password, IP and port number
$proxies[] = 'username:password@IP:port';  // Some proxies require user,   password, IP and port number
$proxies[] = 'username:password@IP:port';  // Some proxies require user,     password, IP and port number
$proxies[] = 'username:password@IP:port';  // Some proxies require user,  password, IP and port number


if (isset($proxies)) {  // If the $proxies array contains items, then
$proxy = $proxies[array_rand($proxies)];    // Select a random proxy from the array and assign to $proxy variable
}
$ch = curl_init();
if (isset($proxy)) {    // If the $proxy variable is set, then
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);    // Set CURLOPT_PROXY with proxy in $proxy variable
}
$url="https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=8kXQWNChIsTSvgSZ3J24DA#q=pakistan&*";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$html = $dom->load($page);

$title=$html->find("title",0);
echo $title->innertext;
```

Comment: You are one hundred percent sure that the service you are testing allows the PUT method?

Comment: @takendarkk no , get some help from internet but it didn't work .. when i remove that like which include 'PUT' , then page goes blank

Comment: Well, you need to read about the service and find what methods it allows.

Comment: @takendarkk do you have any sample code like this ? it may help , i tried this http://scrape-google-search.compunect.com/ but no success

Comment: I don't know why you think sample code will help. Before writing any code you first need to find out what methods the web service allows you to call. Without that information nothing else matters.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right you are looking for a budget solution for scraping Google, that's why you switched out for the proxymillion provider in the sample code you linked  in comments ?

You can not scrape with massively shared proxies (that's the provider you took), Google will spot them either directly or within a few pages and block.
Also using "&ei=8kXQWNChIsTSvgSZ3J24DA" is not the best idea, that's not a default entry into Google and will probably link your scrape request with your browser (where you have that parameter from originally).

If you look for a budget solution you can consider using a scraping service (php source code here: http://scraping.services/?api&chapter=Source%20Code ), that's cheaper than private proxies in most cases and allows to scrape ten thousands of keywords for a few USD.

Alternatively, if you want to continue that route I would suggest testing your proxymillion performance using a simple bash script.
Use curl or lynx in a bash script (If you use linux, otherwise you can do the same on windows with MinGW/msys) and just make them access Google with the proxies. See if it works at all or if you get blocked within a few pages.
But even if you succeed: any shared proxy provider will be unreliable in "performance".